# context menu for Selected item on a DiagramSurface in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, telerik

I have a UI which is a diagramSurface object.
While running the application i drag and drop a element(kind of a label) on top of it.
I want to implement a CONTEXTMENU for this object.

I have Done this

```
<DiagramSurface>
     <DiagramSurface.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Header="Save" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
         </ContextMenu>
     <DiagramSurface.ContextMenu>
</DiagramSurface>
```

By doing this , i am able to see the contextMenu if i click on surface where the object is not present.
How to avoid this? I want to show the context menu only on the rightclick of the element.

Comment: well remove specifying the `ContextMenu` from `DiagramSurface.ContextMenu` to remove it from appearing everywhere within the `DiagramSurface`. Define the `ContextMenu` as a xaml resource and when you drag and drop your label control (where-ever/however) you do it, assign the `ContextMenu` to that item there by retrieving the `ContextMenu` from resources.

Comment: Post the full XAML and relevant code. I have no idea what that `DiagramSurface` thing is.

Comment: @HighCore, a quick online search shows that the `DiagramSurface` control is an extended `Canvas` from Telerik.

Comment: @Sheridan Then this question should be tagged `Telerik` too.

Comment: @VIV the solution you gave works if my control(element) is defined in XAML.But im defining the element in a class. What are my other options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Viv says (although I'm not sure why he didn't say it in an answer), the `ContextMenu` will appear when you right click *anywhere* on the control that you add it to. Therefore, if you add it to the `DiagramSurface`, it will appear when you click anywhere on that control. To fix your problem, remove the declaration from the `DiagramSurface` control.

Now, you need to add it to the control(s) that you drag and drop. You can do as @Viv says and define your `ContextMenu` in the `Resources` section:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Save" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then set it as the `ContextMenu` of the drag drop element from code:

```
ContextMenu menu = (ContextMenu)Application.Current.FindResource("ContextMenu");
element.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

Comment: the solution you gave works if my control(element) is defined in XAML.But im defining the element in a class. What are my other options ?

Comment: I found a workaround .I created a event in the dagram surface and set the visibility of the contextMenu to hidden..                                                        <DiagramSurface MouseRightButtonUp ="MouseRightButtonUp"><DiagramSurface.ContextMenu><ContextMenu visibility="Hidden" /> </DiagramSurface.ContextMenu> </DiagramSurface> ..continued..

Comment: ..continued   Then in the event raised i found the position of the eventclick and then the type of element ..If it is same as the element i dragged and dropped , i set the visibility to Visibile.  and this worked